# Swift: "Cannot invoke subscript" : setting an objects members up by handing it a class's array at an index

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I'm having an issue while programming in Swift. After i create an Instance of the SchedulePatientsTest class I begin to get this error: *Cannot invoke 'subscript' with an argument list of type '(name:$T4, email: $T9, ssn: $T14, dob: $T19)'*

Since I'm quite new to Swift I'm having trouble debugging it and googling hasn't helped much. I know it's complaining about the subscript of the array but I can't understand why. Thank you for your help!

```
import UIKit

struct SchedulePatientsTest {

let patientNames = [ "John Lennon", "Paul McCartney", "George Harrison", "Ringo Starr" ]
let patientEmails = [ "jlennon@beatles.com", "pmccartney@another.edu","george@something.com","drummer@beatles.org"]
let patientSSN = [ "123-45-6789","333-22-1123","567-39-9282","888-88-8888"]
let patientBirthDates = [ "05/01/1951", "06/23/1964","09/05/1955", "02/28/2001"]
let doctorNames = [ "John Smith", "Jane Doe", "Mary Jones", "Beth Garcia"]
let doctorEmails = [ "John Smith", "Jane Doe", "Mary Jones", "Beth Garcia" ]
let doctorSSN = [ "445-25-3382", "582-10-9983", "180-38-0038", "343 - 34-9875" ]
let doctorBirthDates = [ "06/03/1941", "10/10/1950", "12/25/1965", "07/19/1964" ]
let specialty = [ medicalSpecialties.GENERAL_MEDICINE, medicalSpecialties.PEDIATRICS, medicalSpecialties.GENERAL_MEDICINE, medicalSpecialties.ONCOLOGY]

    init()
    {

    }

}

class Patient {

var name  : String = ""
var email : String = ""
var ssn   : String = ""
var dob   : NSDate = NSDate()
init(name: String, email : String, ssn : String, dob : NSDate) {
    self.name = name
    self.email = email
    self.ssn = ssn
    self.dob = dob

}

    func getName()->(String)
    {
        return(name)
    }

}

class Doctor : Patient {

var specialty : medicalSpecialties

    init(specialty: medicalSpecialties,name: String, email : String, ssn : String, dob : NSDate) {
    self.specialty = specialty
    super.init(name: name, email: email, ssn: ssn, dob: dob)
    }

 }

enum medicalSpecialties {
    case GENERAL_MEDICINE
    case PEDIATRICS
    case ONCOLOGY

}

let CMYK = SchedulePatientsTest()
let P1 = Patient(name: CMYK.patientNames[0], email: CMYK.patientEmails[0], ssn: CMYK.patientSSN[0], dob: CMYK.patientBirthDates[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a vague error message, but the error occurs because you are passing a String instead of an NSDate to the Patient initializer.

`let patientBirthDates = [ "05/01/1951", ...]` creates an array of String objects, not date objects. The Patient initializer expects an `NSDate` for its `dob` parameter.

**String vs NSDate**

The code `["05/01/1951", "06/23/1964"]` does not create an array of NSDate objects, even if the variable is defined as `patientBirtDates: [NSDate]`. What this is, is an array of string literals. These string literals are 'converted' into `String` objects. If you want to create an array of NSDate objects, you need to actually instantiate NSDate objects:

`let patientBirthDates = [
    NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 100),
    NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 200),
    NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 300)
]`

Which method of creating NSDates you use is up to you, check the [available ininitializers](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/init).

Comment: Thank you Rengers this helps out! I fixed the array containing all the dates to specifying that it was of type NSDate. But it spits out an error saying NSDate does not have a member named element. Do you happen to have any insight on this? If not I appreciate your help so far!

Comment: Can you post your updated code regarding creation of the array?

Comment: let patientBirthDates : NSDate = [ "05/01/1951", "06/23/1964","09/05/1955", "02/28/2001"]                                                                             let doctorBirthDates : NSDate = [ "06/03/1941","10/10/1950","12/25/1965", "07/19/1964" ]              error is above. Thanks!

Comment: I've added some more explanation about creating an array of NSDate objects.